# Which Text falling and flipping animation preset or plugin is used in after effects

Tags: after-effects

If you open this [video on vimeo](https://vimeo.com/31836169).

Then fast forward to 00:56 on the timeline you can see a text animation where the blocks of text appear like there are being flipped and falling. I want to know what plugin or pre-set animation they are using in After Effects to achieve the same.

If you need more clarity on the question please let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

**They haven't used a preset or plugin.** They have animated it.

Achieving this effect in After Effects is done by [enabling 3D on the layer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/aftereffects/cs/using/WSC6FF4D87-B70E-430f-B432-09061F7FCAFBa.html), positioning the [anchor point](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/aftereffects/cs/using/WS3878526689cb91655866c1103906c6dea-7dd2a.html#WS3878526689cb91655866c1103906c6dea-7dada) and then [animating the rotation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/aftereffects/cs/using/WS3878526689cb91655866c1103906c6dea-7e33a.html).

Comment: no believe me, its a preset or plugin. there is 50 odd videos with the same effect. I Knew it can be done via 3D and rotation but its time consuming. Thanks

Comment: I want to second OrangeBox's answer. It's not "time consuming".

Comment: The steps are literally: Set anchor point to the top of the layer, keyframe the X rotation to -90 degrees, add another keyframe for +50, then another for -30, +20, +15, 0. Then just copy those keyframes and paste it to your 50 videos :)